# Qual biblioteca usar para pausar o sistema no lugar de getch()?

Tags: c, console

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int  main()
{
    int x=4, y=7;
    printf("&X:%X &Y:%X x e y (%d,%d)\n",&x,&y,x,y);

    int *px, *py;
    px = & x;
    py = & y;

    printf("px:%X py:%X *px e *py (%d,%d)\n",px,py,*px,*py);
    getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar o [`getchar()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) ou o [`system("Pause")`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/system). Dependendo da plataforma pode usar algumas opções próprias.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Uso o Dev, pesquisando aqui descobri que se eu adicionar stdlib.h ele aceita o system("PAUSE") , obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Cara . .system("Pause") roda um comando off-process  - eu diria que é a pior opção possível.

Comment: O fato é que não _Existe_ algo definido universalmente em C para uma leitura sincorna de teclado - mas existem chamadas que pausam o programa até a leitura de uma linha de `stdin` - o progrmama que impria a instrução para o usuário apertar  "enter" e use uma dessas - qualquer outra coisa é muito suja.  Programas mais sofisticados ou não vão usar uma interface C.L., ou são pra um púlbico que já está na linha de comando pra rodar o programa.

Comment: @jsbueno a questão é que isso só é útil para fazer um testezinho rápido assim, então tanto faz o que está usando. Tem que ser pragmático.

Comment: não - os professores ensinam nas escolas isso, e os alunos se formam sem saber a diferença - não é uma questãod e pragmatismo. Pragmático aí é `scanf(); `

Comment: @jsbueno aí quase todas respostas aqui estarão erradas e o uso de `scanf()` também costuma ser criticado. Pragmático é olhar o contexto e usar o que é mais simples para aquele cenário. Se o cara se tornar realmente um programador C ele vai aprender o que é ruim em cada situação. Se ele fizer esse tipo de confusão ele não sobrevive 3 dias trabalhando com essa linguagem.